# Error: QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlcomponent, qqmlapplicationengine

I try to register a type, but I'm getting this error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:5 module "Komut" is not installed
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
qmlRegisterType<Execom>("Komut",1,0,"Execom");
```

Comment: You seem to register the type after you load the engine.

Comment: ^ That's likely the problem. Happens to me often. :D

Comment: So,  is there any solution?  Or is this just a bug or smth.

Comment: You should the 2 lines, i.e. register the type **before** `engine.load`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
qmlRegisterType<Execom>("Komut",1,0,"Execom");
```

Do this:

```
qmlRegisterType<Execom>("Komut",1,0,"Execom");
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

Comment: Failed to load ' QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component ' when build for android.